# How to receive Win32 Messages from WPF windows hosted in Win32?

Tags: wpf, winapi, clr

I have loaded a WPF window in my Win32 application:

```
case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
        System::Windows::Interop::HwndSourceParameters p;
        p.WindowStyle = WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD;
        p.PositionX = 100;
        p.PositionY = 100;
        p.Width = 600;
        p.Height = 600;
        p.ParentWindow = System::IntPtr(hDlg);
        Globals::source = gcnew System::Windows::Interop::HwndSource(p);        
        Globals::source->RootVisual = gcnew MyControl();
        return TRUE;
    }
```

Now i want to handle WPF window events by receiving win32 messages in my application.
How can i do this?

Comment: I don't have an answer for your specific problem, but a workaround would be to move your Win32 program into a .DLL and call it via interop from a WPF program. This is probably easier in the long run.